# objects and arrays using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array which consists of 31 objects(it is something like our schedule of month) and i want to display the single object data which is in todays activity in my html page in form of table.below i have given an example of datahow can i do it with jquery?

```js
var mySchedule = [
{
    "Date":"1",
    "Time":"9:30AM",
    "Work":"Mathematics"
},
{
    "Date":"2",
    "Time":"9:30AM",
    "Work":"Science"
},
{
    "Date":"3",
    "Time":"9:30AM",
    "Work":"Social"
}];
```

Comment: post your code you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```js
var mySchedule = [
{
"Date":"1",
"Time":"9:30AM",
"Work":"Mathematics"
},
{
"Date":"28",
"Time":"9:30AM",
"Work":"Science"
},
{
"Date":"3",
"Time":"9:30AM",
"Work":"Social"
}
];

var todayData = $.grep(mySchedule, function (element, index) {
    return element.Date == new Date().getDate();
});

if(todayData!=undefined && todayData.length>0){     
   $("#divResult").html(JSON.stringify(todayData));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```